# Получить стиль с xml

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

Всем привет работаю на apache poi надо через xml получить стиль ячеек а именно 'объединение'. Сделал таким вот образом

```
<Cells wrap_text="true" mergeR="0" mergeR1="0" mergeC="0" mergeC1="8" font_size="11" font="Calibri" font_bold="true" text_align="2" vertical_align="1" border_top="0" border_left="0" border_right="0" border_bottom="0">
          <width>21</width>
          <cell_value>3. Жыл соңына жылжымалы құрам</cell_value>
</Cells>
```

А в самом классе

```
spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
    records.getMergeR(),
    records.getMergeR1(),
    records.getMergeC(),
    records.getMergeC1())
);
```

Есть ли альтернативный способ это сделать?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 // Объединить ячейки(startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn)
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2));
```

тут подробней написано http://www.programru.com/blog/MYTO0ADMwITz.html